# How to deprecate generated Xtext elements?

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I am developing a dsl with Xtext. I want to deprecate some of the language elements. I have an Xtext file from which the language elements are generated. I want those elements to be shown to be deprecated.

Adding @Deprecated over an element does sadly nothing, even though the editor does not complain. I could not find anything regarding deprecation and Xtext.

Answer (score 1):

the

```
        validator = {
            generateDeprecationValidation = true
        }
```

in the workflow does not help?

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

@Deprecated 
Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

this will generate

```
public abstract class AbstractMyDslValidator extends AbstractDeclarativeValidator {

    @Override
    protected List<EPackage> getEPackages() {
        List<EPackage> result = new ArrayList<EPackage>();
        result.add(org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.MyDslPackage.eINSTANCE);
        return result;
    }

    @Check
    public void checkDeprecatedGreeting(Greeting element) {
        addIssue("This part of the language is marked as deprecated and might get removed in the future!", element, MyDslConfigurableIssueCodesProvider.DEPRECATED_MODEL_PART);
    }
}
```

so that this unit test will fail

```
@ExtendWith(InjectionExtension)
@InjectWith(MyDslInjectorProvider)
class MyDslParsingTest {
    @Inject ParseHelper<Model> parseHelper
    @Inject extension ValidationTestHelper
    @Test
    def void loadModel() {
        val result = parseHelper.parse('''
            Hello Xtext!
        ''')
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result)
        val errors = result.eResource.errors
        Assertions.assertTrue(errors.isEmpty, '''Unexpected errors: «errors.join(", ")»''')
        result.assertNoIssues
    }
}
```

results in

[image: Editor]

Comment: In 

language = XtextGeneratorLanguage {

validator = {
            generateDeprecationValidation = true
        }

}

? No, sadly this seems to do nothing. Is adding @Deprecated over the definition in the <language>.xtext file maybe wrong?

Comment: no that works fine. can you please give detailed steps of what you are doing

Comment: also: which Xtext version do you use?

Comment: We use version 2.17.
We are creating a VSCode extension for a dsl an the dsl. The extension should show certain elements as deprecated. I have put this `@Deprecated
Button:
    {Button}` in the language xtext file and the validator in the XtextGeneratorLanguage in the Generator.mwe2 file. But VSCode shows us nothing. If it is just a problem with VSCode, should I be able to see something in the generated file for "Button"? Either in the Interface or the impl? Because there is nothing there as well

Comment: no its generated into the validator. you should be able to reproduce this with a unit test (you can easily debug there too)